# JavaScript HTML5-Canvas - Drawing an Arc with SetInterval Causes Jagged Edges

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, setinterval, animated

I'm trying to draw a donut chart, and so far I've been successful.  The problem is that when trying to animate the arc by combining `stroke()` with `setInterval()`, it works, but it does not look smooth, and produces jagged edges.  I tried using `clearRect()` to clear the canvas after the animation was done and re-add the final version of the animation, but I must have been using `clearRect()` wrong, because it did nothing.  If you have any ideas on how to get this looking good, I'd really appreciate it.

You can see my current code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4mJCy/ and below:

Body:

```
<canvas id="Donutchart" width="215" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.  Please Upgrade to the latest version of Chrome, Firefox, or Safari.</canvas>
```

JavaScript:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("Donutchart");
var maincircle=canvas.getContext("2d");
maincircle.beginPath();
maincircle.arc(107,107,100,0,2*Math.PI);
maincircle.fillStyle="#FF0000";
maincircle.fill();



var currentEndAngle = 1.5;
var currentStartAngle = 1.5;

var pie1 = setInterval(draw, 15);

var counter = 0;

function draw(){


    if(counter >= 101){



    } else {

        var startAngle = currentStartAngle * Math.PI;
        var endAngle = (currentEndAngle) * Math.PI;

        currentEndAngle = currentEndAngle + 0.01;

        var counterClockwise = false;


        var donutslice1=canvas.getContext("2d");    
        donutslice1.beginPath();
        donutslice1.arc(107,107,75,startAngle,endAngle);
        donutslice1.lineWidth = 50;
        donutslice1.strokeStyle="#222";
        donutslice1.stroke();

    }



    counter++;

}


var innercircle=canvas.getContext("2d");
innercircle.beginPath();
innercircle.arc(107,107,50,0,2*Math.PI);
innercircle.fillStyle="#FFF";
innercircle.fill();
```

Answer (score 1):

The jaggies are caused by repeatedly over-writing your arcs.

Instead, refactor your code to clear the canvas with each animation loop.

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/xNLEQ/

Something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: white; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var currentEndAngle = 1.5;
    var currentStartAngle = 1.5;

    var pie1 = setInterval(draw, 15);

    var counter = 0;

    function draw(){

      if(counter >= 101){

      } else {

        var startAngle = currentStartAngle * Math.PI;
        var endAngle = (currentEndAngle) * Math.PI;

        currentEndAngle = currentEndAngle + 0.01;

        var counterClockwise = false;

        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        // red
        drawCircle(75,"#FF0000");
        // gray
        drawDonut(startAngle,endAngle);

      }

      counter++;
    }

    //
    function drawDonut(startAngle,endAngle){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(107,107,75,startAngle,endAngle);
        ctx.lineWidth = 50;
        ctx.strokeStyle="#444";
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    //
    function drawCircle(radius,color){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(107,107,radius,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.lineWidth = 50;
        ctx.strokeStyle=color;
        ctx.stroke();
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```