# How to make HTML canvas' lines smoother for drawing equations

Tags: html, canvas

Trying to make a graphing utility. I am trying to make the lines smoother. I don't think the problem is with how I draw the lines on the canvas, but rather with how I calculate the x and y coordinates.

## HTML

```
<canvas></canvas>
```

## JS

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
let c = canvas.getContext('2d');

// set the graph origin to middle of the canvas
const originX = window.innerWidth / 2;
const originY = window.innerHeight / 2;

c.strokeStyle = `rgba(240, 40, 40, 0.9)`;
c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(originX, originY);

// calculate x and y values for the equation "x^3"
for (let x = -60; x < 60; x = x + 0.1) {
  let y = x**3;
  draw(x, y);
}

function draw(x, y) {
  // Calculated the canvas specific coordinates
  let calculatedX = originX + x * 30;
  let calculatedY = originY + -y * 30;
  c.lineCap = "round";
  c.lineWidth = 1;
  // draw the line
  c.lineTo(calculatedX, calculatedY);
  c.stroke();
}
```

I tried the solutions from responds to other line-smoothing question, but they didn't work. So I think the problem is with the the `for` loop or the `draw function`.

### live site: https://etasbasi.github.io/simple-grapher/dist/

Comment: Add c.beginPath() in you draw function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript HTML5-Canvas - Drawing an Arc with SetInterval Causes Jagged Edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899403/javascript-html5-canvas-drawing-an-arc-with-setinterval-causes-jagged-edges)